# Call action when home buttom pressed iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to call action on home button ? 
I need something like "are you sure to quit app" and wait for yes or no. 
I don't need any code or so. I just need to make sure it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Apart from not being able to add an action to the home button, in iOS you can't quit an app programatically anyway and pressing the home button doesn't quit any apps.

Answer (score 5):

In short, no. you can't block the home button action, neither the user is expecting this to happen. 
If you have to perform any kind of saving, you can do it in the application delegate object in the method `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

[Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Apple does not allow you to do this, as it would make the overall user experience of iOS horrible. Can you imagine if every developer added this functionality to their app?

Comment: Thank you guys! So is there any other way how to prevent from unintended home button pressing while app is running? I mean, how to prevent from lets say 2 years old child grabs your phone press home button and call someone, write email, etc....

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to implement applicationDidEnterBackground, then set up a local notification that instantly notifies the user with an alert, with a button that opens the app and one that does nothing. But you cannot intercept the home button press like you would with shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier